# Is there a better alternative to a logit / probit regression when all dependent variables are dichotomous?

Tags: regression, logit, probit, binary-data

I'm working on a clinical trial dataset with binary response. All independent variables are also binary. My first impulse was to simply run a standard logit / probit regression and be done with it. But after thinking about it for a little longer, I kept thinking: is there something else I could do? My concerns arose from the fact that all variables on the RHS (right hand side, i.e., independent variables) are also binary (which is a first for me).

Any suggestions?

Comment: These are certainly the standard methods - what makes you think there could be something better?

One possible alternative is classification trees.

Comment: Logistic regression (also probit, etc) does not make any assumptions about the distribution of your RHS variables. LR is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I wasn't just too confident about having only binary variables on the RHS. However, as gung noted, there are no distributional assumptions about the RHS, so LR should be fine. It was a matter of self-confidence really. What do you mean by "standard methods"? Log-linear ANOVA or something like it?

Comment: Can't optimal scaling regression be an alternative? Although the OP asked for a better alternative...

Comment: If you want something more usefull, you must tell us what is the goal of your analysis!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: I'm building a binary clinical diagnostic model (diseased x not diseased) in which the X's are all dichotomous (presence/absence of clinical sign or symptom).